# Extracting lower triangle and project it into another 2D space

Tags: python, numpy

Assume we have `array` as below

```
arr_g=np.tril(np.random.rand(3,3),-1)
```

Which, something like below (note that the value might diffrent since I did not made the seed constant)

```
0.00000,0.00000,0.00000
0.11089,0.00000,0.00000
0.15405,0.11389,0.00000
```

Then, I would like to extract only the lower tri value, using `tril_indices_from`

```
lower_idx=np.tril_indices_from(arr_g)
```

Extracting only the lower tri value

```
A_1=list(arr_g[lower_idx])
```

However, I have no clue how to present this list of value into the following form

```
0.00000,0.00000,0.00000
0.11089,0.00000,0.00000
0.15405,0.11389,0.00000
```

p.s: The value might be different, but the logic remains

Appreciate for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
X = np.zeros((3, 3))
X[np.tril_indices_from(X)] = A_1
```